# Euclid Algorithm in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        unsigned int u;
        unsigned int v;
        unsigned int temp;


        NSLog(@"Enter two numbers: ");
        scanf("%u%u", &u , &v);

        while (v != 0)
        {
            temp = u % v;
            u = v;
            v = temp;
        }


        NSLog(@" Greatest Common Factor: %u" , u);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above program requires the user to input two integers. It then calculates greatest common divisor.

- Case 1: If a user in inputs `10 2` as the two values the answer is 2
- Case 2: What if the user reverses the integer to `2 10`? ( answer is still 2)

In the first case:  `u = 2` since `v = 2`, but in the second case  `u = 10` since `v = 10`

My question is why do I still get 2 as the answer of the second case? I will appreciate it if anyone can help me understand this concept.

Comment: If you want to understand it, trace the code by hand.  Your sample case is small enough to do this easily.

Comment: Learning to use a debugger to step through code is really important, and this is a good time to try it, since it's a relatively simple problem.

Comment: You appreciate that `2` is the correct answer in both cases, so this code is producing the correct answer? You're just asking how Euclid's algorithm works?

Comment: @pjs , I already traced the program by hand and and I get 10 all the time for the second case. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @Tommy , yes I want to understand how this program works...

Comment: @Uchenna Then you're doing what you think is supposed to happen rather than correctly following the "directions" given by your code.

Comment: @pjs ,  please can you tell me how the program works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some prints to your loop to understand what's going on:

```
 1  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 2  
 3  int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
 4      @autoreleasepool {
 5          unsigned int u, v, temp;
 6          printf("Enter two numbers:\n");
 7          scanf("%u%u", &u , &v);
 8          while (v != 0)
 9          {
10              temp = u % v;
11              printf("(11) u=%u v=%u temp=%u\n", u, v, temp);
12              u = v;
13              printf("(13) u=%u v=%u temp=%u\n", u, v, temp);
14              v = temp;
15              printf("(15) u=%u v=%u temp=%u\n", u, v, temp);
16          }
17          printf("Greatest Common Factor: %u\n" , u);
18      }
19      return 0;
20  }
```

Then we can see what's happening:

```
Enter two numbers:
2 10
(11) u=2 v=10 temp=2
(13) u=10 v=10 temp=2
(15) u=10 v=2 temp=2
(11) u=10 v=2 temp=0
(13) u=2 v=2 temp=0
(15) u=2 v=0 temp=0
Greatest Common Factor: 2
```

So on the first pass through the loop, by line 11 we've set `temp` to `u % v`, which is 2 (because 2/10 = 0 remainder 2). In fact, whenever `u < v`, `u % v == u`, so whenever `u < v`, `temp == u`.

By line 13, we've copied the value of `v` into `u`. And by line 15, we've copied `temp` into `v`. Remember that when `u < v`, `temp == u`. Therefore whenever `u < v`, the first pass through the loop has the effect of swapping `u` and `v`.

Comment: "So on the first pass through the loop, by line 11 we've set temp to u % v, which is 2 (because 2/10 = 0 remainder 2). In fact, whenever u < v, u % v == u, so whenever u < v, temp == u." That was what I missed.  Thanks you so much....

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a space between the `%u` arguments in `scanf()` else how is the scanner going to know when the first integer ends and the second starts?

```
scanf("%u %u", &u , &v);
```

Also add some error checking and looping:

```
while (scanf("%u %u", &u , &v) == 2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your speculation about needing a space is incorrect (check the [POSIX spec for `fscanf` for more info](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html)), and you didn't address Uchenna's actual question.

Answer (score 0):

If you (correctly) hand trace your `2 10` example, you'll find that when you get to the bottom of your loop for the first time `u` and `v` will have been swapped.  It has flipped over to case 1, and so will give the same answer.

As for why it works, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).